# Design models with two 'one-to-many' relationships in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, database-design

I'm having a problem to design my database in ASP.NET MVC 3 using Entity Frameworks. I've followed some tutorials and tryed to adapt to my need. First time using ASP...

I have three tables: Person, Category and Example.

One Example will be in a Category that belongs to a Person, the other way around: one Person might have several Categories and each of those might have several examples.

I think I should design it with two 'one-to-many' relationships. That is my models:

```
public class Person 
{
  public int PersonID {get; set;}
  public int Name {get; set;}
  public string Text {get; set;}
  public virtual ICollection<Category> {get; set;}
}

public class Category
{
  public int CategoryID {get; set;}
  public int PersonID {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public virtual ICollection<Examples> Examples {get; set;}
  public virtual Person Person {get; set;}
}

public class Examples
{
  public int ExamplesID {get; set;}
  public int CategoryID {get; set;}
  public string Title {get; set;}
  public string Body {get; set;}
  public virtual Category Category {get; set;}
}
```

I can create the Category and the Person, no problem, even using the @Html.DropDownList helper, the problem is when I try to create the Example, I wanted to populate the second dropdown with Ajax but couldn't do it and suddenly I realize there might be a flaw in my db design, In my Example model I will store the Category but not the Person, as the latter will be in already bound to the Category model, isn't it?

I'm kinda lost...
If needed I can post the Controller and/or views, but I think the problem lies in the model.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? There doesn't seem to be a problem with your design (if what you want is a `one-to-many` between `Person` and `Category` and then a `one-to-many` between `Category` and `Example`). But I think you might be asking how to load a person with its categories, and at the same time all of the example for those categories, is this the case?

Comment: Hum, I thought it wasn't working because of my model design. When I try to create an Example I can select the Category (that will be stored in the table) but I can't filter only the Category related to the Person.
The thing is: the Category is an Example Category, not a Person Category. Does it make sense?

Comment: I think you might need to include some code as to what you are trying to do, or what you've done so far. If you are trying to add an `Example` to a `Category` then the `Category` should already have the `PersonId` that it belongs to.

Comment: Just figured out, the problem was on my views, not on my model. Thanks, @SOfanatic!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
public class Person 
{
  public int PersonID {get; set;}
  public int Name {get; set;}
  public string Text {get; set;}

  [ForeignKey("PersonID")]
  public virtual ICollection<Category> {get; set;}
}

public class Category
{
  public int CategoryID {get; set;}
  public int PersonID {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}

  [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
  public virtual ICollection<Examples> Examples {get; set;}

  [ForeignKey("PersonID")]
  public virtual Person Person {get; set;}
}

public class Examples
{
  public int ExamplesID {get; set;}
  public int CategoryID {get; set;}
  public string Title {get; set;}
  public string Body {get; set;}
  public virtual Category Category {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Oh, I've figured out! The problem wasn't on my models but on my view!
Thanks, @michael!